# Setup FFMpegCore in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, import, ffmpeg, wrapper

I am confused on the basics of using a library. I understand that there is a library called FFMpeg and a wrapper called [FFMpegCore](https://github.com/rosenbjerg/FFMpegCore) so we can use FFMpeg with C#, correct? I downloaded both [FFMpeg and FFMpegCore](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/converting-video-with-ffmpegcore/) and I have them in my project's folder. Although I didn't perceive any class named FFMpegOptions in either of the file's folders.
I am stuck on how to actually set it up so I can use it in my little project, I never downloaded someone's library before. Can somebody please walk me though the motions of connecting the three of them together?

So far I experimented with:

- Add a reference to my project, but there doesn't seem to be any .dll, .tlb, .olb, .ocx or .exe files to add
- Add an existing project to my solution. There is a project called FFMpegCore.csproj but adding it raises a missing SDK error. Weirdly enough, opening the same project as a standalone doesn't raise any issues which makes me thing the operation I am trying is inadequate.

I am sure this is a silly and easy setup to perform but I just don't know enough to find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you must download and install ffmpeg on your machine, (to test that it is working correctly, open a CMD and execute "ffmpeg", it will return the installed version.

[image]

Second, create a new project, (I recommend .NETFramework) once your project is created, it is necessary to install the package from NuGet, this function is found in tools> NuGet Package Manager> Manage packages for solutions...>

[image]

Then search for FFmpegCore and install it in your project,

[image]

The necessary dependencies will be added, now you can start programming with this Framework,
[image]

I recommend the FFMpeg.cs class as an example of the documentation, to start with.

[image]
Good Luck.